# Passing react-router-dom Link component as a render prop is failing

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to pass a `react-router-dom` `Link` component as a render prop to a component, but am running into some issues:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/xjm35923qo

The error that I receive when passing `<Link>hi</Link` as a render prop is `Invariant Violation
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

That seems fair enough, but if I instead pass in something like `() => <Link>hi</Link>`, there is no error, but there is a warning (`react-dom.development.js?7f13:507 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.`) and the link doesn't render.

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around these error messages -- what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should import Link as a named import:

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"
```

and you need to wrap your app with a Router object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import